# how do I make a select query with a date in the doctrine?

Tags: postgresql, symfony

I can't output data for a certain year? How do I do this with Doctrine?
My sql query is for example:

```
select * from cc_take_parties tp
join case ccc 
on tp.case_id = ccc.id
where ccc.case_type_id in (1, 5)
and tp.parties_type_id in (4,1)
and ccc.in_date = '2000-01-01'
```

My Doctrine Query is:

```
 public function getData($date)
    {
        return  $this->createQueryBuilder('takeParties')
            ->join('takeParties.case', 'case')
            ->join('case.caseType', 'type')
            ->andWhere('type.id in (1, 5)')
            ->andWhere('takeParties.partiesType in (4,1)')
            ->setParameter('date', $date)          -- doesn't work
            ->andWhere('case.inDate = :date')      -- doesn't work
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Here inDate does't work.
Error is

*
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 203: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER, got '.'

QueryException
SELECT takeParties FROM CourtCaseBundle\Entity\TakeParties takeParties INNER JOIN takeParties.case case INNER JOIN case.caseType type WHERE type.id in (1, 5) AND takeParties.partiesType in (4,1) AND case.inDate = :date
*

```
class TakeParties
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReferenceBundle\Entity\ParticipatingParties")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $partiesType;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CourtCaseBundle\Entity\CourtCase", inversedBy="takeParties", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     */
    private $case;
}
class CourtCase
{
      /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReferenceBundle\Entity\TypeCase")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */

    private $caseType;
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     */
    private $inDate;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data, all as text - **no images**.  Further *doesn't work* is useless. Do you get an error? If so what is the exactly complete error. If no error then what do you get and why in that not correct?

Comment: "Here inDate does't work. " - this is terrible description. In what way it does not work? Does it end with an error? Does it return nothing? .... You have to be specific. It would be also good to see your entity as doctrine uses DQL and you are not doing native query.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code my assumption is that you pass in a string

Change your function to this

`public function getData(\DateTime $date){ ...`

that means, the $date you pass in must be of object `\DateTime`

you can create those from strings like this https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

and change the order of your query builder e.g. use

```
->andWhere('case.inDate = :date')
->setParameter('date', $date)
```

you can read as well here: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.12/reference/query-builder.html search for datetime